# React Testing Library cannot work when I use useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, babeljs, react-testing-library

I have one component with Redux `useSelector`, when I want to test the render text, it shows error message on `useSelector` and with the error message: `could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`. I have put `<Provider>` to the top level component, where is the wrong part on my testing code? The app itself is running correct.

TopLevel component:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from "./redux/store"

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("test")
)
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { fetchPosts, showName } from "./redux/actions/posts"
import Main from "./component/main"

function App() {
    const { posts, name } = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPosts())
    }, [])

    const handleShowName = useCallback((textName) => {
        dispatch(showName(textName))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App" data-test="appComponent">
            <button onClick={handleClick}>get post</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleShowName("test")}>Show name</button>
            <section className="main">
                <div>project name: {name}</div>
                <Main posts={posts} />
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

app.test.js

```
import React from "react"
import App from "./App"
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

it("render a div with text 'project name'", () => {
    const { container, getByText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText("project name:")).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

When I test my redux action and redux reducer, my testing is working. So the `Jest` setting should be fine.

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./setupTests.js"]
}
```

setupTest.js

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: false }],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                corejs: 3,
                helpers: true,
                regenerator: true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a redux context for the component being tested (*in isolation*).

Minimum is to create a simple [wrapper component](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper) (see also [custom render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render)), similar to the provider in the app, passed in the options of the `render` test utility.

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from "./redux/store"

const ReduxWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
);

it("render a div with text 'project name'", () => {
  const { container, getByText } = render(
    <App />,
    { wrapper: ReduxWrapper },
  );
  expect(getByText("project name:")).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

See the Redux docs for testing [connected components](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

The gist is to create a custom render function that includes your redux store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// Import your own reducer
import store from "./redux/store";

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';
// override render method
export { render };
```

Then for testing you import the custom `render` utility

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "../testUtils";

it("render a div with text 'project name'", () => {
  const { container, getByText } = render(
    <App />,
    // pass any options here like initial state, custom store, etc...
  );
  expect(getByText("project name:")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```